# Filter query URI in elasticsearch based on dates

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, uri, elastic-stack, elk

Not able to filter the elasticsearch data based on dates. Not able to correctly figure out how to use "gt", "gte" in the URI to fetch Elasticsearch data.

```
localhost:9200/index/date:{"gte":2019-01-01 00:00:00}
```

Need to fetch all the docs that have date > 2019-01-01 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges). You can do it like this:

```
localhost:9200/index/_search?q=date:>=2019-01-01
localhost:9200/index/_search?q=date:[2019-01-01 TO *]
```

Comment: Error : "type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse date field [2018-01-01] with format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S]"}]

Comment: I have already tried the updated version. Still facing the same error.

Comment: And try without the `T` between the date and the time, since your format seems to not have it

Comment: I have tried it without the T also. The error in parsing still exists.

Comment: I've reproduced your case and updated my answer, both of the above queries work for a document having a `date` field with the following date `"2019-08-20 15:18:38.1"`

Answer (score 0):

The write method to query using elasticsearch was

`localhost:9200/index/_search?q=date:["2018-01-01+00:00:00.0"+TO+"2019-09-02+00:00:00.0"]`

as the format mentioned was  [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S]